# c# using .ToString() Method on webbrowser.url converts %26 ampersand automatically?

Tags: c#, url, webbrowser-control, urldecode, ampersand

I'm trying to do something like this so I can grab the information out of the URL from a c# webbrowser, I later break up the decoded url using & as an endpoint for the sections:

```
string theURL = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(webBrowser1.Url.ToString().Replace("%26","and")).Replace('+',' ');
```

My problem is that it seems when I call .ToString() on the webBrowser1.Url it automatically converts %26 to & effectively ruining my URL. I need to preserve the %26 until I can handle it myself and replace it with something else.

--

I tried an alternative method like this as well but param1 always came back blank for some reason, I could never get anything out of it:

```
string queryString = webBrowser1.Url.Query;
var q = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
var param1 = q["paramname"];
```

This also gave me blanks:

```
foreach (var element in q) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(element.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `webBrowser1.Url.OriginalString`. That should preserve the original URL.

The `ToString` method of `System.Uri` is overridden and returns the canonical representation. Check the example which just shows this [in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx).